# When dataframe is removed from memory in pyspark,? How to remove a dataframe explicitly?

Tags: pyspark

Here is the scenario example, i want to remove df1 as soon as the same is no more used any where the code to free up memory -

```
df1 = spark.sql("Select 1 as X")
df2 = df1.withColumn("Y", df1["X"])

# here if I want to remove df1 then what should be the code.

df2.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

If we use df.persist() or some cache level we can unpersist the Dataframe. But here we are nowhere using any caching.
If you really want to flush out the memory check garbage-collection-tuning

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/docs/tuning.md

Note: Dataframe doesn't hold data.

Comment: I do not want to flush out entire memory, but wanted to remove a specific dataframe from memory.
Also, when we executes an Action on dataframe then all the dataframe must be evaluated and holds intermediate result sets, please correct me if my understanding is not correct.

Comment: We have two types of rdd/df operation i.e. Transformations and Actions. Every time a Transformation is performed it will result in the addition of a step to the DAG and whenever an action is performed it traces back using this DAG, meaning how this df/rdd was created then brings in the data to memory and use it. But whenever we cache/persist it, the data stays in memory and won't be re-computed for subsequent actions.